# htaccess configuration for two websites on a shared server

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, shared-hosting

Basically I have a shared server with an existing site and a new site. On most shared hosting accounts(linux) I have, the file structure is something like this:

```
- public_html 
-- firstsite.com 
-- secondsite.com
```

For the server in question the structure is more like this:

```
- public_html 
-- all of the folders and files of the first site loose in this directory 
-- secondsite.com
```

So if I try to access secondsite.com from a browser, I am sent here instead: 
`http://firstsite.com/secondsite.com`

...which is obviously incorrect. My hosting support told me that if I rename the htaccess file used by firstsite.com the secondsite.com will resolve as: 
`http://secondsite.com`

I obviously just can't disable my htaccess file because that will bork the first site.

So I'm looking at my htaccess file and thinking this is the problematic line:

```
### Only allow access without the www. #### 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^firstsite\.come$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://firstsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm thinking I need a similar set of rules that pertain to `secondsite.com`?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First your `RewriteRule` will always be executed since you have an invalid domain name in `RewriteCond` and it will always be different from that host (you have .come).

Second I think you could try to add this as your first set of rules in your `.htaccess file`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondsite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secondsite.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to change your rule from:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^firstsite\.come$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://firstsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.firstsite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://firstsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So that when the host is `secondsite.com`, the rule won't try to redirect back to first site.com